# How to stop dollar signs from being expanded in a variable when running SSH commands on a remote host?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables

So am creating a bash script that uses the `usermod --password` command to set user password on remote servers. I have successfully used the `openssl passwd -1` command to encrypt my password and I have stored them in an environment variable as follows:

```
export $MYPASS=$(openssl passwd -l easypass)
```

Now when I echo my variable, it looks good! but when I use in the script, the password is not working, it turns out that the dollar sign in expanded when I ssh into the remote host .. How Can i stop this from happening?

SO locally it works amazing

```
echo $MYPASS
$1$bNs852RL$oFd5/p4jCV6TuDdEJprNZ0
```

Check what happens when I ssh:

```
 ssh webserver1 "echo $MYPASS"
/p4jCV6TuDdEJprNZ0
```

Any hints will be greatly appreciated. One very dumb way to fix it will be putting escape character before every dollar sign but I feel there is a better way ... thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: @Jetchisel no it didn't ..... I know the differences between single and double quotes .. my question is more advanced .. am talking about a specific scenario here -- remote hosts.

if i do single quotes, I won't be able to even get my variable value all together

Comment: Variable assignment the `$` is not allowed on the left hand side. Not sure if `export` expands/accepts it...

Comment: `ssh webserver1 "echo '$MYPASS'"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your command is evaluated twice: once to run in your local shell, and once again when executed on the remote host. You therefore need to escape the result of the expansion.

Fortunately, bash4+ makes this easy with the @Q quote modifier:

```
var="tricky value with space, \\, \$s, 's and \"s"
ssh localhost "echo ${var@Q}"
```

Answer (score 0):

using an escape quote is a simpler way but another way is, to use a single quote before and after your `$MYPASS` variable, then you can run `tr -d "'"` to  remove the single quote after, if you need to before using the environment variable.